# Can I use APRS TCP/IP abroad?

Tags: legal, aprs

I'm in Europe and sometimes while I'm driving I send my position using aprsdroid on my phone through aprs-is service. One local ham are threatening me because I'm digipeating using my foreign callsign from Brazil.

Am I breaking any regulation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the local ham is misunderstanding that you're using the internet and not amateur radio to report your position.

You're not doing anything wrong.

I can understand his initial confusion if he's not used to seeing foreign callsigns on maps as a result of APRS-IS. Perhaps share this link with him: https://www.aprs-is.net

Comment: Thanks for your reply, was exactly what I thought. The guy didn't even identify himself in the emails. He created an address like citywatcher@ and started threatening me to stop because he had already notified the authorities. Even trying to explain that I wasn't transmitting anything via RF he keeps threatening. Anyway thanks a lot for the guidance.

Comment: Ah some people just want to be angry. I would just ignore him. Safe travels to you!

Comment: Maybe tell him what frequency you are transmitting on (cell).

Comment: @user10489 no. Honestly, just don't engage. Don't give him any fodder. The goal here is not to convince him in a cheeky manner. That won't work, and even if it did, it's no use. Let that guy be angry. It's neither your problem nor your fault. What the goal is is to be left alone. And emails are quite ignorable.